# Can I make std::optional<std::exception>::value() return the (polymorphic) inherited exception, and not std::exception?

Tags: c++, exception, c++17, stdoptional

Apparently, throwing and catching `std::optional<std::exception>::value()` cannot be handled polymorphically. First if we consider

```cpp
try
{
    throw std::logic_error("blah ..");
}
catch(const std::exception& e)
{
    std::cout << "E: " << e.what() << std::endl; // OK, outputs "blah .."
}
```

We get get the expect output, but if we try

```
std::optional<std::exception> error = std::logic_error("Booo ..");
try
{
    throw error.value();
}
catch(const std::exception& e)
{
    std::cout << "E: " << e.what() << std::endl; // NOPE, outputs "std::exception"
}
```

The exception object got sliced.

I understand that this is because I'm actually throwing optional's template type, which is `std::exception` and **not** `std::logic_error`. That is, we basically changed the `throw` expression in the first example to

```
std::exception err = std::logic_error("Blah ..");
throw err;
```

which gives the same behavior.

So **how** can I make my `std::optional<std::exception>::value()` return a derived exception? Does it have to contain a pointer?

Comment: This cannot be done with `std::optional`, since the C++ standard requires `std::optional` to not use any dynamic allocations, i.e. the object is stored as a member of the object itself, not using a pointer to an object. You can never prevent object slicing when using `std::optional` for this reason: there just isn't enough memory for the object to store other, potentially larger subclasses of the object wrapped in `std::optional`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pass exceptions around in a value type that may or may not hold them, along with type erasure of the exception type, you turned to the wrong tool from the standard library. That's what [`std::exception_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception_ptr) is for: it exists to pass a thrown (or ready to to be thrown) exception handle around.

```
auto error = std::make_exception_ptr(std::logic_error("blah .."));
// stuff 
try {
  std::rethrow_exception(std::move(error));
} catch (std::exception const& e) {
    std::cout << "E: " << e.what() << std::endl; 
}
```

Here it is [live on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:67,endLineNumber:7,positionColumn:67,positionLineNumber:7,selectionStartColumn:67,selectionStartLineNumber:7,startColumn:67,startLineNumber:7),source:%27%23include+%3Cexception%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdexcept%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++auto+error+%3D+std::make_exception_ptr(std::logic_error(%22blah+..%22))%3B%0A++++//+stuff+%0A++++try+%7B%0A++++std::rethrow_exception(std::move(error))%3B%0A++++%7D+catch+(std::exception+const%26+e)+%7B%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22E:+%22+%3C%3C+e.what()+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B+%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:55.43769462350251,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:g131,compilerName:%27%27,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:3,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-O3+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors+-pthread+-g+-fsanitize%3Daddress,undefined%27,overrides:!(),source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+gcc+13.1+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:44.5623053764975,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

`std::exception_ptr` is how the standard library bridges the gap between library code that needs to move exceptions around points of execution, and the core exception mechanism. Due to this, it isn't limited to just exceptions derived from `std::exception`, as we can throw arbitrary types in C++.